# How to fill word template with picture controls from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, com, ms-word, vsto

I need to make an application that opens a template made by customer, with special names/titles/tags, whatever we will agree upon, and then fill it from the database based on the customer's search.

However, if the customer made a template like this one [image]

Now we have two ContentControls (wdContentControlRichText & wdContentControlPicture)

**Questions are:**

1- How to make multiple pages in the same document from the same chosen template.

2- (Most Important) How to set the PictureContentControl Image from vb code.

***Notes:***

I tried my best to search and look for similar questions, yet no one seems to solve my problem. What I have reached is that I can loop through the content controls, but I can't cast the PictureContentControl from *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word* Object to *Microsoft.Office.Tools* Object.

Also all solutions I found on the net, includes **"Globals.Factory"** which doesn't seem to ever be valid for my code, as my *Globals* doesn't contain the *Factory* Object.

**I'm using the references:**

- Microsoft.Office.Core
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
- Microsoft.Office.Tools
- Microsoft.Office.Common
- Microsoft.Office.Common.v4.0.Utilities
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.v4.0.Utilities
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime